# I cannot find setup.py in my OSX babel installation to import the cldr babel files, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, macos, setup.py, egg, python-babel

I have been trying to use babel on my iMac (OSX Mavericks, I installed python and babel using MacPorts) but I get this error message :

```
[...]
writing PO template file to ./locale/messages.pot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pybabel", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Babel==2.0-dev-20131218', 'console_scripts', 'pybabel')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/frontend.py", line 1151, in main
    return CommandLineInterface().run(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/frontend.py", line 665, in run
    return getattr(self, cmdname)(args[1:])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/frontend.py", line 947, in extract
    sort_by_file=options.sort_by_file)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/pofile.py", line 427, in write_po
    messages = list(catalog)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/catalog.py", line 552, in __iter__
    for name, value in self.mime_headers:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/catalog.py", line 337, in _get_mime_headers
    locale='en')))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/dates.py", line 609, in format_datetime
    locale = Locale.parse(locale)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/core.py", line 284, in parse
    language = get_global('language_aliases').get(language, language)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/core.py", line 53, in get_global
    _raise_no_data_error()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel/core.py", line 25, in _raise_no_data_error
  raise RuntimeError('The babel data files are not available. '
RuntimeError: The babel data files are not available. This usually happens because you are using a source checkout from Babel and you did not build the data files.  Just make sure to run "python setup.py import_cldr" before installing the library.
```

I can't run the following command because I cannot find the setup.py file in the .egg archive on my Mac

```
>python setup.py import_cldr
```

Trying to run the setup.py on another version of babel I downloaded resulted in this error, but even if I could do it it would not solve my problem I think :

```
> python setup.py import_cldr
running import_cldr
Local copy '/Users/Ailete/Downloads/Babel-1.3/cldr/core-23.1.zip' not found
Downloading 'core-23.1.zip'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/download_import_cldr.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "scripts/download_import_cldr.py", line 82, in main
    urlretrieve(URL, zip_path, reporthook)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",     line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 244, in retrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Ailete/Downloads/Babel-1.3/cldr/core-23.1.zip'
```

Any idea about how to install the CLDR file for the .egg installation ?

Here is the content of the babel package on my machine :

```
> cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/
> ls
EGG-INFO    babel
> cd babel
> ls
__init__.py     core.py     localedata.py   numbers.py  support.py
__init__.pyc    core.pyc    localedata.pyc  numbers.pyc support.pyc
_compat.py      dates.py    localtime       plural.py   util.py
_compat.pyc     dates.pyc   messages        plural.pyc  util.pyc
```

And the results of some commands I tried :

```
> cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-2.0_dev_20131218-py2.7.egg/babel
> python setup.py import_cldr
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> python setup.py install
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: This looks like a packaging issue with MacPorts’ Babel.  You should not have to get missing data files yourself after installing some software.

Comment: That's the way you have to install it as explained in the [official documentation](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/installation/)

Comment: Yes, the babel docs only describe how to install with a Python-specific packaging tool (pip/setup.py), but if you use a system package manager like MacPorts, these instructions don’t apply.

Comment: You were partly right, in fact I was not looking at the right place on my HD, I answered my own question even if my problem is not solved yet as I have to figure out how to configure my system properly now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was looking at a version of babel installed with the system ...

I found out that MacPorts install things in :

```
/opt/local/
```

The cldr files I need seem to be located in :

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/babel/localedata/
```

I now need to find how to set the paths properly on Mavericks ... But my problem seem to be that of the system not using the proper version of Babel.

Thank you for your answers, I will make a new question to help me with the path configuration.

Comment: I found a way o solve [my configuration problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945319/how-to-configure-my-python-2-7-to-use-the-correct-babel-installation-on-my-osx-m), but I don't know if it is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get into the directory that it is in and then type:
"python setup.py install" (without the quotes).

~Thomas

Comment: How can I do that if there is no setup.py?